# Change UITabBarItem image on selection (Xcode 12, Swift)

Tags: swift

In my UITabBarDelegate's tabBar(_:didSelect:) function I am trying to toggle a tabBarItem's image.  This works with iOS 14, but when I test with iOS 11 it does not change the image.

I tried wrapping in a DispatchQueue.main.async {} and calling tabBar.setNeedsDisplay() and tabBar.setNeedsLayout(), but this did not help.

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    switch item.tag {
        case 0:
            if publishAudio == false {
                item.image = UIImage(named: "mute_off")
            } else {
                item.image = UIImage(named: "mute_on")
            }   
        default:
            preconditionFailure("Unexpected item tag: \(item.tag)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, when setting the image, set the `image` and `selectedImage`.

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    switch item.tag {
        case 0:
            if publishAudio == false {
                item.image = UIImage(named: "mute_off")
                item.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "mute_off")
            } else {
                item.image = UIImage(named: "mute_on")
                item.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "mute_on")
            }   
        default:
            preconditionFailure("Unexpected item tag: \(item.tag)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make it from the storyboard using the UITabBar image for each viewController like the image: [image]

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].image = UIImage(named: "your image name")
    // items![0] index of your tab bar item.items![0] means tabbar first item

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "your image name")
```